# WF project: express edition

Tags: workflow-foundation

Is there a visual studio express edition to develop WF applications?

Answer (score 4):

The designers for workflow are missing in the express editions. But you still can do workflow.

For an example look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WF/WFExpress.aspx) link.